# replace many td cell text with format

Tags: jquery

I trying to get this jquery working on cells in a table, dynamic generated td's so cannot place a class on the TDs. The last two columns have flat phone numbers in them and trying to format them to US format. Its working on just the first row, and doesnt do any replacements on other rows, but the console logs that it gets there. Can you see what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

```
$('table td:last-child, table td:nth-last-child(2)').each(function () {
var cellText = $(this).html();
if (cellText.length > 0) {
    console.log("Did " + $(this).html());
    $(this).html(cellText.replace(/(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)/, '$1-$2-$3'));
}
});
```

Comment: This really has nothing to do with C# or asp.net so I'm removing those tags.

Comment: Working for me. http://jsfiddle.net/n7cyE/1446/

Comment: Could you please share your HTML because the jQuery seams to be working just fine as @Azim shows.

Comment: Reviewed the HTML per Azim and Diego and found some unclosed td tags that caused this issue. The jquery did work as written. Thank you